# Page Break error new page

Tags: jasper-reports

Print a set of invoices in `PDF`, I put Page Break `$V{PAGE_COUNT}==16` and a group  to break invoice number. All OK, but if the invoice rows = 16 the group total invoice print in a new page. Any ideas?

```
   <group name="documento" isResetPageNumber="true" footerPosition="ForceAtBottom"><groupExpression><numero fattura></groupExpression><groupFooter> <band height="230" splitType="Immediate"><textField><reportElement> totali fattura.....</band></groupFooter></group> <pageHeader><band height="350" splitType="Stretch"> <textField><reportElement><textField><reportElement>testata fattura</band></pageHeader><detail><band height="16" splitType="Stretch"><break>   <reportElement><printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE‌​_COUNT}==16]]></printWhenExpression>  </reportElement></break></band></detail></ja‌​sperReport>
```

Comment: what you are trying to do ? print 15 record in each page ?

Comment: 16 record in each page, but if invoice is 16 records, total print in new page and not in footer. thanks

Comment: are you using page  Footer Band ?

Comment: no i use group footer for number invoice. the totall must be printed for every invocie. i reset number page per every group.

Comment: please post your jrxml

Comment: <group name="documento" isResetPageNumber="true" footerPosition="ForceAtBottom"><groupExpression><numero fattura></groupExpression><groupFooter> <band height="230" splitType="Immediate"><textField><reportElement> totali fattura.....</band></groupFooter></group> 
<pageHeader><band height="350" splitType="Stretch">
<textField><reportElement><textField><reportElement>testata fattura</band></pageHeader><detail><band height="16" splitType="Stretch"><break> <reportElement><printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_COUNT}==16]]></printWhenExpression> </reportElement></break></band></detail></jasperReport>

Comment: I resolved , removing Page break , band group document set 0 , Put fields total invoice in pagefooter . for print  totals invocie in only last page of the invoice I had <printWhenExpression> new Boolean ($ F { } FINEAR .toString ( ) . equals ( " END " ) ). Ireport no good for print document.